# Input is array of words-Output should be Array of Arrays that groups anagrams.

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
def combine_anagrams(words)
    a1 = []
    words.sort do |x, y|
        a = x.downcase.chars.sort.join
        b = y.downcase.chars.sort.join
        if a == b
            a1.push(x,y)
        end
    end
end

x = ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four', 'scar', 'creams', 'scream']
combine_anagrams(x)
```

I used the sort method in the array because it's the only method that I found that would let me pass it two elements of the array to compare.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.group_by{|s| s.downcase.chars.sort}.values
# => [["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["for"], ["potatoes"], ["four"], ["creams", "scream"]]
```

Comment: Very nice! I assumed they were all in pairs, and missed the possibility they would have triples or singles.

Comment: This is the way. I'd only propose a rename of variables: `x` -> `words`, `s` -> `word`.

Comment: This is great sawa thank you! Could you elaborate as to what this replaces in my code and where to place it.  I keep getting undefined method errors.

Comment: Just realized that sawa's code replaced all of mine in one line. Wow!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs on `combination`. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination

Try something like this (*untested*)

```
def combine_anagrams(words)
    a1 = []
    words.combination(2).each do |x, y|
        a = x.downcase.chars.sort.join
        b = y.downcase.chars.sort.join
        if a == b
            a1.push(x,y)
        end
    end
end

x = ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four', 'scar', 'creams', 'scream']
combine_anagrams(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to group ***all possible*** anagrams, you probably don't want to only be comparing two elements at a time.  Do you intend to leave out anagrams that only have a single item (i.e. 'for', in your example)?  Hence you should probably be using a different function which iterates each element at a time.

**after-the-fact**

@sawa has the right idea, I think.  It combines the correctness of what you're trying to achieve with the succinctness of Ruby.